# slider control similar to ipad default calendar app

Tags: ios, ipad, calendar, uislider

I would like to know how to implement the slider similar to the one in the Ipad default calendar application. I have attached the image below [image: ipad calendar application]

If you see at the bottom, it acts like a slider which allows us to select any month either by just pressing it or sliding to it.

It would be great if anyone could tell me the name of that control. I tried using UISlider but I see that it allows only 3 options:

- `setThumbImage`
- `setMinimumTrackImage`
- `setMaximumTrackImage`

If that control is indeed a slider control, could anyone tell me how I would be able to insert multiple images/ text

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question. I would like to see more of its kind on StackOverflow. How to realize something? Which framework components can be utilized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can be achieved by using UIScrollView. Add UIButtons programmatically having background images and text as well on them as per your requirement.**

You can refer [tutorial1](http://kwigbo.tumblr.com/post/758575763/uiscrollview-image-gallery-tutorial) [tutorial2](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/) in which on screen only 1 page(Image) is displayed. You need to do some calculation for applying same logic to fit your requirement. i.e. Your scrollview will be smaller(in height) and bigger(in width) as displayed in image, you will be adding UIButtons in spite of images and most important at a time displaying more than 1 item but it won't be difficult. The Main part is only programmatically scrolling.

Comment: thanks jennis.. I did the same thing yesterday.. created a scroll view having buttons in them... awesome links btw.. very helpful... will definitely ask if I get stuck somewhere...

Comment: The Tutorial1 link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

It may be more complex than you'd like, but you could make your own:

Make a background that has UILabels for the dates

Make a selection box

In the UIViewController you could put something such as:

touchesMoved - 
Make the selection box's x value equal to the touch

touchesEnded - 
Make the selection box's x value equal to the touch's last x value

The touches moved would allow dragging of the selection box, and the touchesEnded would allow tap selection.

Then you would simply animate the selection box to the x value.

(This is an extremely simplified version, but you could do this pretty easily.)

Comment: thanks XenElement for the answer.. I actually did it the way similar to what Jennis had posted...